# How can I scroll a Sheild UI chart horizontally at a time based speed

Tags: javascript, charts, shieldui

I was wondering if anyone can offer any advise/examples of using Shield UI charts to show a horizontally scrolling graph over a time period.

I am open to suggestions about how to achieve this but would like to see real-time (per second or less accuracy) scrolling, either by frequent updating of a single graph or perhaps better, simply moving a vertical line marker from left to right across the y-axis to demonstrate the movement of time, relative to a static background chart.

Answer (score 1):

May you specify some more details about what you want to achieve as it is not quite clear? Can you give some image/example how it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at that demo, probably it is something near to what you have asked.

http://demos.shieldui.com/web/line-chart/forex-data

There as you can see you can dynamically rebind chart and simulate live data. Scrolling starts after it is filled with data. Probably that is something similar to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this and the pan/scroll graphs already on the demo site, but neither quite match what I am after. Essentially, if you imagine a timer or clock somewhere next to a graph, if you were to press "go" for every second the timer advances, I would like to be able to advance a timeline marker running vertically through a graph. The graph may start out fully formed i.e. 100% zoomed out, in which case only the timeline marker will change over time.

Comment: Conversely if the graph is zoomed in to say, 50%, there may also be a need to automatically advance the graph horizontally as the clock reached the (right-side) extent of the current view. Is that any clearer (to Chris Evans too)?